# Proving property of Markov chains.

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

There is a proof of the following Markov-chain I don't understand. I have circled in red the two steps I do not understand. Could you please explain the steps for me? [image]

In the proof they also refer to equation 2.4, this is given below here:

[image]